# printing percentage value into decimal swift

Tags: swift, decimal, percentage

[The Result I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahBZR.png)i have three buttons under same IBAction showing different percentages %0, %10, %20.
and I have another button called calculate in another IBAction. so what I want is. when I choose %10 and press calculate I want to print out the 0.1 in the console. this is very beginner question but I m really stuck here
below is my code

```
import UIKit
```

class CalculatorViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var billTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var zeroPctButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var tenPctButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var twentyPctButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var splitNumberLabel: UILabel!



@IBAction func tipChanged(_ sender: UIButton) {
   
   zeroPctButton.isSelected = false
    tenPctButton.isSelected = false
    twentyPctButton.isSelected = false
    sender.isSelected = true
   
}


@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {
}


@IBAction func calculatePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    
}
```

}

Comment: Do you want the print output to be hardcoded, or do you want to convert some inputo to the wanted output? If the latter, which data do you have to convert? Is it a string like "10%", or is it an integer like 10, or something else?

Comment: both if possible

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add the output on the percentage button tapped, e.g. in the `@IBAction` of the "10%" button:

```swift
print("0.1")
```

If you really need to output on the Calculate button tap, you can first determine which percantage button is selected:

```swift
if zeroPctButton.isSelected {
  print("0.0")
} else if tenPctButton.isSelected {
// ...
```

If you don't want to hardcode the output, you need some data to base on. Since you don't show us any model code, we can only rely on the text on the buttons. So, the solution might look something like this (inside the Calculate button's `@IBAction`):

```swift
[zeroPctButton,
 tenPctButton,
 twentyPctButton]
  .filter { $0.isSelected }
  .forEach {
    print("\(Double(($0.titleLabel.text ?? "").filter { ("0"..."9").contains($0) }) / 100.0)")
  }
```

(It takes the text of the selected percentage buttons, filters out only digits from it, converts the resulting digit string to `Double`, and divides the result by `100.0`.)